# Не добавлять элемент в список, если такой уже есть

Tags: javascript, html

Как не добавлять элемент в список, если такой уже есть? Пытаюсь сделать через массив, каждый элемент я записываю в массив и в нем проверяю на совпадения, но скрипт не работает почему-то.

html:

```
<input type="text">
<span class="btn">click</span>
<div class="result"></div>
```

js:

```
function ready() {

    var arr = [];
    document.querySelector(".btn").onclick = function() {
        var val, result, elem, text;

        val = document.querySelector("input").value;
        result = document.querySelector(".result");
        elem = document.createElement("p");
        text = document.createTextNode(val);
        elem.appendChild(text);

        arr.push(elem);
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var txt = arr[i].textContent;
            if (txt == val) {
                return false;
            } else {
               result.appendChild(elem); 
            }
        }
    };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: у тебя всегда должно выполняться return false, потому что ты уже добавил элемент в массив и в нем всегда есть элемент, у которого `textContent` такой же как val

Comment: можете написать пожалуйста я не совсем понимаю как это должно быть

Comment: просто делай push **после** цикла for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var txt = arr[i].textContent;
        if (txt == val) {
            return;
        }
    }
    arr.push(elem);
    result.appendChild(elem);
```